# Drupal.behaviors get results from function

Tags: 7, javascript

I am struggling to understand how this works and I just can not get a grasp of if it. Basically what I am trying to do is get the results from my php function and pass it into ajax to make my page redirect to a certain area.

This is what I have for my php

```
function paydayform_submit($form, &$form_state){

    $entry = payday_parse($form, $form_state);

    /*if($entry['response'] == "sold"){
        print 'success';
    } else {
        print 'failed';
    }*/

    drupal_add_js(array('payday_form' => array('redirect'=>$entry)), 'settings');

}
```

And this is where I am completely lost and in the dark at.

```
(function($){
Drupal.behaviors.payday_form = {
 attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#edit-submit', context).once('payday_form', function () {
        $(this).click(function(){

            //Response from payday_parse($form, &$form_state)
            final_redirect = Drupal.settings.payday_form.redirect;

                    //this comes back as undefined =/
            console.log(final_redirect);

            //if statement giving from the response above.
            if(final_redirect = 'success'){
                console.log('worked');  
            }else{
                console.log('didnt work');
            }
        });
    });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Am I using this correctly? What am I doing wrong that it isnt picking up the function?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with behaviours, but I wonder, is the behaviour supposed to be an object?

Comment: Why close vote on this? Passing arguments from PHP to behaviors is a legitimate Drupal question. @Letharion yes it is supposed to look about that.

Comment: `final_redirect = Drupal.settings.payday_form.redirect;` - where was that variable declared with `var` keyword? If nowhere then why, yes, it *is* undefined / undeclared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ajax_command_settings](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_settings/7). Here is the answer [Drupal.settings merging when using AJAX](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66441/drupal-settings-merging-when-using-ajax)